# Bluemix Liberty Java does not build with Java 8

Tags: java, maven, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

How can I change maven compile java version into version 8?

I applied the following:

```
cf set-env boldStartApp JBP_CONFIG_IBMJDK "version: 1.8.+"     
cf set-env fournHubApp JVM 'openjdk'     
cf set-env fournHubApp JBP_CONFIG_OPENJDK "version: 1.8.+"     
cf restage boldStartApp  
cf restage fournHubApp
```

I already tried the solution from this forum thread:
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/12673/bluemix-and-java8.html

Everything I tried failed.

I am still getting the error:

[image: Screenshot of Bluemix-maven build error]

How do can I change the java version to 8 in bluemix liberty java?

Comment: This command should work. Are you using the default Java Liberty buildpack? Could you please post your manifest.yml? BTW, JRE version 8 is the default one for the Liberty buildpack.

Comment: What the support did to fix this issue was to add 'export JAVA_HOME=/opt/IBM/java8' before 'mvn -B package' in the build shell command that can be accessed when configuring build stage.

Comment: btw, I am only having issues on ibm bluemix... but it perfectly fine in my eclipse-liberty server (local).

Answer (score 2):

The following are the changes done by the ibm support to fix the building issues I am having with regards to using java 8.

Changes in pom.xml:

```
    <properties>    
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>    
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>    
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>    
    </properties>
```

In the build stage pipeline configuration:

Edit, build shell command:

From:

```
    #!/bin/bash        
    mvn -B package
```

To:

```
    #!/bin/bash    
    export JAVA_HOME=/opt/IBM/java8    
    mvn -B package
```

[image: Build Stage Configuration change(s) screenshot]

- manifest.yml

  ```
  applications:
  - disk_quota: 1024M    
          host: xxx    
          name: xxx    
          path: target/GlobalTicket-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war    
          domain: mybluemix.net    
          instances: 1    
          memory: 512M    
          env:    
                  IBM_LIBERTY_LICENSE: L-MCAO-9SYMVC    
                  JVM: openjdk
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I also have tried to run Java on Liberty but it did not work out. So I've found a workound solution for that. You can create a new image from an image listed in DockerHub and use it to create a container.
Here is a Dockerfile of an image that has Java installed in it:

```
FROM java:8-jdk

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get upgrade -y

# Set password length and expiry for compliance with Vulnerability Advisor
RUN sed -i 's/^PASS_MAX_DAYS.*/PASS_MAX_DAYS   90/' /etc/login.defs && \
    sed -i 's/sha512/sha512  minlen=8/' /etc/pam.d/common-password

EXPOSE 80
```

You can create the image using `cf ic` command:

```
 cf ic build --no-cache -t registry.ng.bluemix.net/mycompany/java8:v1 .
```

Comment: when you said you were trying to run Java on Liberty, did you mean a standalone Java application?

Comment: Yes, I tried to run `java -jar myapp.jar`, but it didn't work.